# Spark - how to stop retrying and ignore exception

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running spark locally to understand how **countByValueAndWindow** works

```
val Array(brokers, topics) = Array("192.xx.xx.x", "test1")

// Create context with 2 second batch interval
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ReduceByWindowExample").setMaster("local[1,1]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2)) // batch size 2
ssc.checkpoint("D:\\SparkCheckPointDirectory")
// Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

// Get the lines, split them into words, count the words and print
val lines = messages.map(_._2.toInt)
val keyValuelines = lines.map { x => (x, 1) }

val windowedlines=lines.countByValueAndWindow(Seconds(4),Seconds(2))
//window,interval
//    val windowedlines = lines.reduceByWindow((x, y) => { x + y }, Seconds(4) , Seconds(2))
    windowedlines.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

everything works file till numeric data is supplied on the kafka topic as I am  using toInt ,when a blank string "" is written on kafka topic it fails complaining NumberFormatExceotion that is OK,but the problem is it is retrying this indefinetly again and again and complaining the same NumberFormatException 
Is there any way to control number of time spark will try to convert string to Int ,like Spark should try it only [times] and then move to next batch of data

Comment: I am using Spark 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have used Exception handling as the best feature of java, scala type languages which ensure that the program should not get failed. Here the way I have edited you code, please validate if it's work for you.

```scala
import scala.util.Try

val Array(brokers, topics) = Array("192.xx.xx.x", "test1")

// Create context with 2 second batch interval
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ReduceByWindowExample").setMaster("local[1,1]")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2)) // batch size 2
ssc.checkpoint("D:\\SparkCheckPointDirectory")
// Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

// Get the lines, split them into words, count the words and print

val lines = messages.map(x => {
     val convertedValue = Try(x._2.toInt)
if (convertedValue.isSuccess) convertedValue.get else 0
})

val keyValuelines = lines.map { x => (x, 1) }

val windowedlines=lines.countByValueAndWindow(Seconds(4),Seconds(2))
//window,interval
//    val windowedlines = lines.reduceByWindow((x, y) => { x + y }, Seconds(4) , Seconds(2))
    windowedlines.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Yes this can always be done ,I did this explicitly to see how spark will behave,I believe that if a task was unsuccessful then it should proceed to next task rather than retrying again and again

Comment: That's not the case with spark, you have to handle the situation otherwise either in some case it terminate the whole process or in some cases will iterate over the same error again and again but never skip it.

Comment: Thanks Kshitij for help, got the point.If possible can you share any link if you know any relating to this topic, would of great help

Comment: Here the links -

1. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5945
2. http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-enable-fault-tolerance-td7250.html

Comment: From documentation ,I believe this is fixed in release 1.6.0

Comment: It's yet to be released :) officially.

Comment: please up vote the answer if you've found it somewhat useful.

Answer (score 0):

While there might be a way to configure a maximum number of retries for a specific record, I think the right way to go about this would be to actually handle the exception. I believe the following code should filter out excepted records:

```
import scala.util.Try
...
val keyValueLines = messages.flatMap { case (e1, e2) =>
  val e2int = Try(e2.toInt)
  if (e2int.isSuccess) Option((e2int.get, 1)) else None
}
```

The `flatMap()` transformation removes the `None`'s from the result while extracting the `(Int, Int)` tuple from the `Option` for all other records.